# Invalid column name 'database_id' in sp_blitzfirst

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitzfirst

I am receiving the following in messages when running the `sp_blitzfirst @expertmode = 1` on the following box:

kit version: SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit-20161210

Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit) version 10.50.6000

> Setting up configuration variables
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Invalid column name 'database_id'.
>   Now starting diagnostic analysis
>   Capturing first pass of wait stats, perfmon counters, file stats
>   Beginning investigatory queries
>   Finished running investigatory queries
>   Waiting to match @Seconds parameter
>   Capturing second pass of wait stats, perfmon counters, file stats
>   Analyzing changes between first and second passes of DMVs
>   Analysis finished, outputting results
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Invalid column name 'database_id'.

Here is what I get running `sp_blitzwho`:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Invalid column name 'database_id'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

First, thanks for using our scripts.

Second, sorry you ran into this problem.

For support, the best place to file issues [is here](http://firstresponderkit.org). Just remember to search for issues first before filing.

There's a fix for this in [this commit](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/648). You can grab the version from there to use until this month's release drops.

Thanks!